# Facebook API - Need publish_pages and manage_pages but Failing Review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My code is working properly in dev mode, but I can not get approval to use publish_pages or manage_pages.  I keep failing every review.

The problem is that the software is to be ran as a cron job and there's really no user interface.  This is for an auction website and we want to post a summary of auctions for the next day in our feed.

For some reason they keep saying:

> Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app.  Unfortunately we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually

Right now, if I have the app in dev mode the post submits successfully, but only my user account can see them, so I've been having to leave dev mode on, let the app post, and then turn the app live.

This is less than ideal.  Is there any 3rd party application that has already been approved I can use to post to our facebook page?

Comment: For this kind of app, try to follow the review instructions under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the magic is making sure to mention "this is a server to server application with no user interface" is all that's required to get your app approved.  After doing that, it went through without an issue.